# По какому ГОСТу или стандарту оформлять написанное приложение?

Tags: kotlin, гост

Написал программу на Kotlin для Android, необходимо сделать отчетность по проделанной работе. Как правильно оформлять программу/исходный код программы в документации?

Comment: Спрашивайте у тех, кто будет принимать вашу работу, наверное?

Comment: Тут скорее вопрос не в том, как это будут принимать, а как сделать так, чтобы было наглядно и можно было сослаться на определенный гост или стандарт

Comment: А зачем вообще вам куда-то ссылаться?

Comment: Ни на какой, нет ГОСТов по оформлению Android приложений. Если вы пишете не для универа или какой-нибудь закостенелой госкорпорации — не нужно ссылаться ни на какие ГОСТы (по крайней мере в плане оформления кода), это просто бессмысленная бюрократия.